# Magento: Multiple Attributes with same (identic) values - inheritable?

Tags: magento, inheritance, attributes, magento-1.7, entity-attribute-value

I am about to set up an online store and I am kinda "testing" if magento fits my needs. I think I got the idea behind categorizing and attributing products. But I have a question to the attributes concerning products - or in detail: for configurable products.

**Is it possible to "inherit" attribute values (options) from another existing attribute?**

I'll give you an example to visualize my question:

Let's say we sell boxes. We would have three different types of boxes:

1. uni-color boxes ("box-color")
2. boxes with a seperate "top-color"
3. boxes with a special printing on it, which has its own color ("highlight color")

To assign colors to box type #1, I would have the possible values

- black,
- white,
- orange.

Box type #2 might come as

- black box / black top (it might seem redundant, but there is a difference to uni-colored boxes),
- black box / white top,
- black box / orange top,
- white box / black top,
- white box / white top,
- white box / orange top,
- and so on.

And finally, box type #3 might come as

- black box / black top / black highlight,
- black / white / orange,
- black / black / white,
- etc.

I think you get the idea.

I would like to have one attribute of color-options which I would maintain (like add new colors, delete old ones, etc.) - and use it as all three different types of configurable color sets.

To be able to create configurable products I would add the color-attribute to my special "boxes" attribute set(s). But when it comes to the two-colored-boxes, I am not able to add the color attribute a second time.

Is there any other (simple) way to achieve this? Since I am new to Magento I would not like to dig too deep into the code or even want to develop a module (?).

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your answers :-)

Comment: This will likely be better served over at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that there was this site. Have thought about it, but couldn't find it in the "all sites" drop down list.